# Read multiple file in python and generate one output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script for generating 1 upload file from 1 input file.

The thing is that the input files have started coming in batches, 30-50 at one time.
e.g.:

`1111.xlsx --> upload.xlsx`

`1125.xlsx --> upload.xlsx`

`1176.xlsx --> upload.xlsx`

`1322.xlsx --> upload.xlsx`

The code just converting the input files in the upload format.

Here's what I have done so far (1 input file -> 1 output file):

```
def main():    
    initial_workbook = 'C:/files/1111.xlsx'

    temp_df = pd.ExcelFile(initial_workbook)
    initial_df = pd.read_excel(initial_workbook, sheet_name = "default")

    #drop first 4 rows to set header
    new_header = initial_df.iloc[2]
    initial_df = initial_df.iloc[3:]
    initial_df.columns = new_header

    #drop all rows with no data
    indexNames = initial_df[initial_df['grade'] == 'select'].index
    initial_df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
    initial_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

    output = initial_df.to_excel('C:/files/upload_file.xlsx', index = False)
```

Is there a way to generate one upload file for all the files from the input folder. And once the files input files have been processed, rename them by prefixing `x` in front of it. e.g. `x1111.xlsx`

Comment: will need more info before a concrete answer can be given. If you want to concatenate the outputs to get the results of the batch you can do so too.

Comment: I want to append all the initial_df generated from each file into one upload file

Comment: if all the generated `dataframes` have same columns you can use `pd.concat([df1, df2, ...], axis=0)` and this will give you the final dataframe which you can save as excel. Does this help or shall I post an answer?

Comment: it would help if you could post an answer, since I am not familiar with file handling. How do I read all files at once?

Comment: Currently, I am reading just one file but there are many. Plus how do I rename it after the file has been concatenated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I will approach, for a given batch:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
from pathlib import Path
all_dfs = []
proj_path = Path("C:/files/")

for f in os.listdir(proj_path):
    if f.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print(f"processing {f}...")
        df_tmp = main(proj_path / f)
        df_tmp["file_name"] = f
        all_dfs.append(df_tmp)
        
df_all = pd.concat(all_dfs, axis=0)
df_all.to_excel(proj_path / f"{datetime.now()}_batch.xlsx", index = False)

def main(f):    
    initial_workbook = proj_path / f

    temp_df = pd.ExcelFile(initial_workbook)
    initial_df = pd.read_excel(initial_workbook, sheet_name = "default")

    #drop first 4 rows to set header
    new_header = initial_df.iloc[2]
    initial_df = initial_df.iloc[3:]
    initial_df.columns = new_header

    #drop all rows with no data
    indexNames = initial_df[initial_df['grade'] == 'select'].index
    initial_df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
    initial_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
    
    return initial_df
```

You can potentially enclose the logic for a batch in a function.

Comment: And how do I change the name of the file after its done processing? Need to prefix x in it

Comment: Or is it possible to move the processed files into another folder

Comment: I have appended the datetime stamp to the name and this way you will have all the batch results uniquely named. Also this time information might come handy later :)

Comment: I had one more ques though, is it possible to create a new file, kind of a log file with whole data from all_df[] + a column telling me what all rows came from which filename